# How to use orc-core-1.5.5 in Spark 2.3.3?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, jar, orc

My codes rely on `orc-core-1.5.5` and I need it to run on `Spark-2.3.3`environment. But Spark-2.3.3 has only `orc-core-1.4.4`.

Due to some reason, "--jars" is not allowed for my case. So I tried to use Maven Shade Plugin to add orc-core-1.5.5 into my final jar. But when I submit this jar to Spark-2.3.3, it still says `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.orc.OrcFile$ReaderOptions.getUseUTCTimestamp()Z` (which only exists in 1.5.5 version). It seems that my app didn't use orc-core-1.5.5 inside my jar, but search for this method in 1.4.4 in Spark environment.

the shading part in my pom:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                      <shadedClassifierName>cuda10</shadedClassifierName>
                      <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                          <include>org.apache.orc:orc-core:nohive</include>
                        </includes>
                      </artifactSet>

                    </configuration>

                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After getting the jar, I dig into it and decompile the OrcFile.class. I can see the method "getUseUTCTimestamp()" lying there.

What's the order of the `method search` process? what can I do to use a method that only exists in orc-core-1.5.5, but on Spark-2.3.3?

Updated according to the answer, add `relocations` in `configuration`

```
                  <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                      <pattern>org.apache.orc</pattern>
                      <shadedPattern>org.shaded.apache.orc</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                  </relocations>
```

But I'm getting a new error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.shaded.apache.orc.impl.SnappyCodec
    at org.shaded.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.createCodec(WriterImpl.java:244)
    at org.shaded.apache.orc.impl.OrcCodecPool.getCodec(OrcCodecPool.java:55)
    at org.shaded.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.extractFileTail(ReaderImpl.java:606)
......
```

I can see `org/shaded/apache/orc` lying in my jar.

Comment: Are you sure the class files for the orc 1.55 version are in the shaded jar?  I've done something similar and it's worked for me.  Can you post your maven config for the shade plugin?

Comment: @MikePone I've added part of my pom. orc-core is the only dependency that attached in my jar.

Comment: Double check that the class files from orc 1.5 are actually in the jar file you are using in spark.

Comment: yes, After getting the jar, I dig into it and decompiled the OrcFile.class. I can see the method "getUseUTCTimestamp()" lying there. it's really confusing. @MikePone .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`<relocation>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) directive of the maven shade plugin. This will change the "location" of your dependency so as to not conflict with the spark version.

The shade plugin effectively moves your dependency into a different package location, and rewrites the bytecode of the rest of your project to use the *changed* fully qualified class names, so that it doesn't overlap with spark's dependencies, and allows both versions to exist simultaneously in the JVM.

Comment: I've added this configuration in my pom, and attached it to my jar. And it seems my app is using the relocated orc-core but I was getting a new error like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.shaded.apache.orc.impl.SnappyCodec
` Did I miss anything?

Comment: It looks like perhaps the `SnappyCodec` class was not included in your version of the orc dependency, therefore not included in your jar as the shaded name. One solution would be to `<exclude>` that class from your relocation to fall back on the spark version. Another possibility is to ensure that the dependency's dependency is also embedded.

Comment: Failing back to the spark version could, of course, cause other dependency issues, so I'd recommend attempting the latter solution.